# Unable to deploy a app on netlify , able to build it offline

Tags: reactjs, github, netlify

this is the log that i receive while deploying

'''
    5:06:24 PM: Waiting for other deploys from your team to complete
    5:06:40 PM: Build ready to start
    5:06:48 PM: build-image version: 3031d4c9e432fd7016f6279fc9ad706f9205d845
    5:06:48 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.17
    5:06:48 PM: buildbot version: da42b14a989873e00cc6f36bc354c01953474181
    5:06:48 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
    5:06:49 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build`enter code here`
    5:06:49 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
    5:06:49 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
    5:06:49 PM: git clone https://github.com/kmohan0910/uploadcsv
    5:06:50 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
    5:06:51 PM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'build' versus 'build/' in the Netlify UI
    5:06:51 PM: Starting build script
    5:06:51 PM: Installing dependencies
    5:06:51 PM: Python version set to 2.7
    5:06:52 PM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
    5:06:53 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
    5:06:53 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
    5:06:53 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
    5:06:53 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
    5:06:55 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
    5:06:55 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
    5:06:55 PM: 5.2 is already installed.
    5:06:55 PM: Using Swift version 5.2
    5:06:55 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
    5:06:55 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
    5:06:55 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.4
    5:07:33 PM: > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
    5:07:33 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
    5:07:33 PM: > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js
    5:07:33 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
    5:07:34 PM: > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js-pure
    5:07:34 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
    5:07:36 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    5:07:36 PM: added 1740 packages from 935 contributors and audited 1744 packages in 39.877s
    5:07:38 PM: 66 packages are looking for funding
    5:07:38 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
    5:07:38 PM: found 1 low severity vulnerability
    5:07:38 PM:   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
    5:07:38 PM: NPM modules installed
    5:07:38 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
    5:07:38 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
    5:07:38 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
    5:07:38 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
    5:07:38 PM: Installing missing commands
    5:07:38 PM: Verify run directory
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
    5:07:40 PM: │        Netlify Build        │
    5:07:40 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: ❯ Version
    5:07:40 PM:   @netlify/build 2.0.10
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: ❯ Flags
    5:07:40 PM:   deployId: 5eeca338119e4f34c3fcde52
    5:07:40 PM:   mode: buildbot
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: ❯ Current directory
    5:07:40 PM:   /opt/build/repo
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: ❯ Config file
    5:07:40 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: ❯ Context
    5:07:40 PM:   production
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: ┌────────────────────────────────┐
    5:07:40 PM: │ 1. Build command from settings │
    5:07:40 PM: └────────────────────────────────┘
    5:07:40 PM: ​
    5:07:40 PM: $ npm run build
    5:07:40 PM: > modal@0.1.0 build /opt/build/repo
    5:07:40 PM: > react-scripts build
    5:07:41 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
    5:08:09 PM: 
    5:08:09 PM: Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
    5:08:09 PM: Most CI servers set it automatically.
    5:08:09 PM: 
    5:08:09 PM: Failed to compile.
    5:08:09 PM: 
    5:08:09 PM: ./src/components/Dragdrop.js
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 3:8:   'Dropzone' is defined but never used                                                                             no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 38:6:  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'columndata'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    5:08:09 PM: ./src/components/Bodal.js
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 4:8:    'Modal' is defined but never used                     no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 6:8:    'Basic' is defined but never used                     no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 7:8:    'Table' is defined but never used                     no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 14:9:   'handleClose' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 16:10:  'inputfield' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 16:22:  'setinput' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 17:9:   'tablecoloums' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 19:17:  'setvalue' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 31:9:   'setinput1' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 36:9:   'handleemail' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 41:9:   'handlefirstname' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 45:9:   'handleadd' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 50:9:   'setlastname' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM: ./src/components/compo.js
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 6:8:     'Basic' is defined but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                                 no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 9:8:     '$' is defined but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                                     no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 12:8:    'Dropzone' is defined but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                              no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 14:8:    'SearchIcon' is defined but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                            no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 34:22:   'setinput' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                     no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 45:10:   'userList' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                     no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 45:20:   'setuser' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                      no-unused-vars
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 106:6:   React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'columndata', 'show', and 'show1'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setshow1(s => ...)' if you only need 'show1' in the 'setshow1' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 282:46:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                                                                                                                                                                                                               eqeqeq
    5:08:09 PM:   Line 360:43:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                                                                                                                                                                                                               eqeqeq
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR! errno 1
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR! modal@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR!
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR! Failed at the modal@0.1.0 build script.
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    5:08:09 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2020-06-19T11_38_09_749Z-debug.log
    5:08:09 PM: ​
    5:08:09 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
    5:08:09 PM: │   "build.command" failed    │
    5:08:09 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
    5:08:09 PM: ​
    5:08:09 PM:   Error message
    5:08:09 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
    5:08:09 PM: ​
    5:08:09 PM:   Error location
    5:08:09 PM:   In Build command from settings:
    5:08:09 PM:   npm run build
    5:08:09 PM: ​
    5:08:09 PM:   Resolved config
    5:08:09 PM:   build:
    5:08:09 PM:     command: npm run build
    5:08:09 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
    5:08:09 PM: Caching artifacts
    5:08:09 PM: Started saving node modules
    5:08:09 PM: Finished saving node modules
    5:08:09 PM: Started saving build plugins
    5:08:09 PM: Finished saving build plugins
    5:08:09 PM: Started saving pip cache
    5:08:10 PM: Finished saving pip cache
    5:08:10 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
    5:08:10 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
    5:08:10 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
    5:08:10 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
    5:08:10 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
    5:08:10 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
    5:08:10 PM: Started saving go dependencies
    5:08:10 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
    5:08:12 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
    5:08:12 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
    5:08:12 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
    5:08:13 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m24.289509635s
    '''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to avoid the warnings in your log

This trace specifies that warninigs = errors

> 5:08:09 PM: Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.

And after that:

> 5:08:09 PM: ./src/components/Dragdrop.js   5:08:09 PM: Line 3:8:
>   'Dropzone' is defined but never used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line
>   38:6: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'columndata'.
>   Either include it or remove the dependency array
>   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps   5:08:09 PM: ./src/components/Bodal.js
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 4:8: 'Modal' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 6:8: 'Basic' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 7:8: 'Table' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 14:9: 'handleClose' is assigned a value but never
>   used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 16:10: 'inputfield' is assigned
>   a value but never used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 16:22:
>   'setinput' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars   5:08:09
>   PM: Line 17:9: 'tablecoloums' is assigned a value but never used
>   no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 19:17: 'setvalue' is assigned a
>   value but never used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 31:9:
>   'setinput1' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 36:9: 'handleemail' is assigned a value but never
>   used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 41:9: 'handlefirstname' is
>   assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line
>   45:9: 'handleadd' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 50:9: 'setlastname' is assigned a value but never
>   used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: ./src/components/compo.js   5:08:09
>   PM: Line 6:8: 'Basic' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 9:8: '$' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 12:8: 'Dropzone' is defined but never used
>   no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 14:8: 'SearchIcon' is defined but
>   never used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 34:22: 'setinput' is
>   assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line
>   45:10: 'userList' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
>   5:08:09 PM: Line 45:20: 'setuser' is assigned a value but never used
>   no-unused-vars   5:08:09 PM: Line 106:6: React Hook useCallback has
>   missing dependencies: 'columndata', 'show', and 'show1'. Either
>   include them or remove the dependency array. You can also do a
>   functional update 'setshow1(s => ...)' if you only need 'show1' in the
>   'setshow1' call react-hooks/exhaustive-deps   5:08:09 PM: Line 282:46:
>   Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq   5:08:09 PM: Line 360:43:
>   Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq

Comment: how to set that

Comment: That's how Netlify works, I'm not sure you can change/overwrite that property. Avoid your warnings in your local console. ./src/components/Dragdrop.js, ./src/components/Bodal.js and  ./src/components/compo.js are the ones Netlify is complaining about.

Comment: it used to work earlier without error ... I solved it though ...to anyone who is encountering problems just try firebase instead to deploy your app its easier than it seems.